# React Material TextArea styling is broken

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am following [this example](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/getting-started/templates/sign-in-side/SignInSide.js) for a basic login screen. Very new to React but I found it to be pretty simple so far.

Unfortunately, as you can see in the screenshot below, the `TextArea`s look really bad! It seems like the inner padding is messed up.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

The fields should look like this:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FunctionComponent, useState } from 'react';

import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import InputAdornment from '@material-ui/core/InputAdornment';
import Visibility from '@material-ui/icons/Visibility';
import VisibilityOff from '@material-ui/icons/VisibilityOff';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export interface ComponentProps {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  name: string;
  showPassword: boolean;
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    height: '100vh',
  },
  paper: {
    margin: theme.spacing(8, 4),
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  sideImage: {
    backgroundImage: '',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[900],
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    backgroundPosition: 'center',
  },
  form: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    width: '100%',
  },
  logo: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
  },
}));

export const ReactLoginComponent: FunctionComponent<ComponentProps> = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
    name: 'Davey Jones',  // TODO: un hardcode this!
    showPassword: false,
  });

  const handleChange = (prop) => (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event.target.value });
  };

  const handleClickShowPassword = () => {
    setValues({ ...values, showPassword: !values.showPassword });
  };

  const handleMouseDownPassword = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  const login = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(`Welcome ${values.name}`);
  };

  return (
    <Grid container component="main" className={classes.root}>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={8} md={7} lg={4} component={Paper} elevation={0}>
        <div className={classes.paper}>
          <Avatar
            src="../../../assets/img/logo/logo-half.png"
            alt="Branding"
            className={classes.logo}
          />
          <Typography component="h1" variant="h6">
            Welcome Back {values.name}
          </Typography>
          <form noValidate className={classes.form}>
            {/* Email */}
            <TextField
              required
              fullWidth
              autoFocus
              id="email"
              variant="outlined"
              label="Email"
              margin="normal"
              type="text"
              value={values.email}
            />
            {/* Password */}
            <TextField
              required
              fullWidth
              id="password"
              variant="outlined"
              label="Password"
              margin="normal"
              type={values.showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
              value={values.password}
              onChange={handleChange('password')}
              autoComplete="current-password"
              InputProps={{
                endAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment position="end">
                    <IconButton
                      aria-label="Toggle password visibility"
                      onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                      onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                    >
                      {values.showPassword ? <Visibility/> : <VisibilityOff/>}
                    </IconButton>
                  </InputAdornment>
                ),
              }}
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary"/>}
              label="Remember me"
            />
            <Button
              fullWidth
              type="submit"
              variant="contained"
              size="large"
              className={classes.submit}
              onClick={login}
            >
              Sign in
            </Button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={false} sm={4} md={5} lg={8} className={classes.sideImage}>

      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

Versions:

- `"react": "^16.12.0"`
- `"@material-ui/core": "^4.10.2"`
- `"@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1"`
- `"@material-ui/styles": "^4.10.0"`

Edit:

I should've mentioned that I'm using React inside an Angular application that is using Angular Material and has global overrides for certain components. This is probably where the issue is coming from. How can I negate those global changes from this React component specifically? Or could I override them in this component?

Comment: Here's a sandbox with your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-cmqti?file=/demo.tsx. Looks fine to me. My guess is that you also have some global styles that are impacting the display.

Comment: Works in safari, chrome, firefox and edge..

Comment: Ryan is right there may be some problem in others files which are affecting this. Tested the code and woks fine in Chrome and Brave.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I'm using the strangler pattern with Angular and React. I think you're right, the styles applied to Angular Material globally are being applied to this React component